# How to trigger onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I would like to know how to trigger the third onclick in Javascript without changing the HTML code. I have tried runCMConversionEventTag(); but no luck.

```
<div id="cartAction_bottom">
            <a href="javascript:continueShoppingLink();" onclick="return runCMConversionEventTag({conversionCategory: 'Shopping Cart', conversionEvent: 'Continue Shopping'})"><img src="http://www.footlocker.com/images/fl/shoppingcart/continue_shopping.jpg" alt="Continue Shopping"></a>

                <a href="javascript:inventoryCheck_panel.open();" onclick="return shopcartCheckoutButtonPress({conversionCategory: 'Shopping Cart', conversionEvent: 'Checkout'})"><img src="http://www.footlocker.com/images/fl/shoppingcart/checkout.jpg" alt="Checkout"></a>

                <div class="centered">or</div>

                <a href="javascript:inventoryCheck_panel.open('paypalexpress');" onclick="return runCMConversionEventTag({conversionCategory: 'Shopping Cart', conversionEvent: 'PayPal Checkout'})"><img src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" alt="PayPal Checkout"></a>

            <p>
        </p></div>
```

Comment: Run `inventoryCheck_panel.open('paypalexpress');`

Comment: How did that comment receive an upvote??  That's in the href attribute, *not* the onclick handler.

Comment: De Vonte wants to simulate a click on the element. Instead of simulating the click, it's easier to run the function directly. runCMConversionEventTag() is just a function which checks something (I assume) and then returns true/false. According to the return value, inventoryCheck_panel.open() gets executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$("#cartAction_bottom a:last").click();
```

`$("#cartAction_bottom")` chooses that div by its id.
`$("#cartAction_bottom a")` would choose all of the anchors inside that div
`$("#cartAction_bottom a:last")` should choose the last anchor in that div.

The `.click()` function will run the click event as if you clicked on that element.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/JKm5t/1/)'s a very primitive jsfiddle to test it with.